# HTML Top Bar background stretch

Tags: html, css

how do you code in html or css to design a top bar maybe with background color of red that will stretch through the screen size?

For example, this is what I normally do which I could not achieve what I want. The below is the example of what I would do in my css.

```
#topbar {
        background-color:red;
        width:1400px;
        height:50px;
}
```

In this case, the red color bar would be cut off at the left top corner. What should I do in html/css so the corner would not be cut off?

Comment: if you have try this please share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVbry/2/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#topbar {
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

If you will give width in pixel then it will not work in all screens. Its better to use % width so it automatically adjust with screen width.

Comment: Why to reset margins and paddings here?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov It ensures that your elements in the code don't have margins and paddings that you don't want. If you reset it to 0 you can assign the margins and paddings with 100% ensurance that your own coded lines will be applied to the elements.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I know what the rule does. ;) I'm asking isn't it excessive in such a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/JVbry/3/

```
 *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#topbar {
        background-color:red;
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Removed comment and +1 for using external CSS. So much easier to read and edit :)

Comment: Yes that whats Im looking for! Thanks! Anyway what * stands for ? I never came across this. So what * should be use for?

Comment: @user2641016 if extra gapping seen our html please use marign:0 and pdding0 * ya use in body css, its removing gapping. if my answer useful you please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly...
Html

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```